# pre processing category data in R

Tags: r, data-preprocessing

Example of data set

```
PRODUCT_ID household_key   BASKET_ID DAY QUANTITY SALES_VALUE STORE_ID RETAIL_DISC TRANS_TIME WEEK_NO COUPON_DISC
1     1082185          2375 26984851472   1        1        1.21      364        0.00          6       1           0
2     1036325          2375 26984851472   1        1        0.99      364       -0.30          6       1           0
3     1033142          2375 26984851472   1        1        0.82      364        0.00          6       1           0
4     8160430          2375 26984851472   1        1        1.50      364       -0.39          6       1           0
5     1004906          2375 26984851472   1        1        1.39      364       -0.60          6       1           0
6     6423775          2375 26984851516   1        1        2.00      364       -0.79          6       1           0
7     9487839          2375 26984851516   1        1        2.00      364       -0.79          6       1           0
8      826249          2375 26984851516   1        2        1.98      364       -0.60          6       1           0
9     1102651          2375 26984851516   1        1        1.89      364        0.00          6       1           0
10    1043142          2375 26984851516   1        1        1.57      364       -0.68          6       1           0
11    1085983          2375 26984851516   1        1        2.99      364       -0.40          6       1           0
12     981760          1364 26984896261   1        1        0.60    31742       -0.79          6       1           0
13     842930          1364 26984896261   1        1        2.19    31742        0.00          6       1           0
14     920955          1364 26984896261   1        1        3.09    31742        0.00          6       1           0
15     937406          1364 26984896261   1        1        2.50    31742       -0.99          6       1           0
16     897044          1364 26984896261   1        1        2.99    31742       -0.40          6       1           0
17    1048462          1130 26984905972   1        1        1.19    31642       -0.80          5       1           0
18     833715          1130 26984905972   1        2        0.34    31642       -0.32          5       1           0
19     866950          1130 26984905972   1        2        0.34    31642       -0.32          5       1           0
20    1022843          1130 26984905972   1        2        0.34    31642       -0.32          5       1           0
21    1071333          1130 26984905972   1        2        0.34    31642       -0.32          5       1           0
22     923972          1173 26984945254   1        1        0.67      412        0.00          7       1           0
23    1131351          1173 26984945254   1        1        0.88      412        0.00          7       1           0
24     824399          1173 26984945254   1        2        1.98      412        0.00          7       1           0
25    1082185            98 26984951769   1        1        0.39      337        0.00          7       1           0
26     965138            98 26984951769   1        2        3.00      337       -0.08          7       1           0
27     878302            98 26984951769   1        3        0.90      337        0.00          7       1           0
28    1087347            98 26984951769   1        1        0.25      337        0.00          7       1           0
29     985911            98 26984951769   1        1        1.25      337       -0.34          7       1           0
30     877180          1172 26985025264   1        1        2.29      396        0.00          4       1           0
   COUPON_MATCH_DISC MANUFACTURER DEPARTMENT BRAND COMMODITY_DESC SUB_COMMODITY_DESC
1                  0            2         34     2            293                166
2                  0           69         34     1            300                391
3                  0            2         34     2            213               1499
4                  0           69         34     1            215               1513
5                  0           69         34     1            235               1695
6                  0          586         18     2             74                941
7                  0          586         18     2             74                941
8                  0           69         18     1             16               1005
9                  0         1266         18     2            231               1593
10                 0          321         11     2             39               2097
11                 0          586         18     2             74               2251
12                 0           69         18     1            104                697
13                 0           69         18     1             72                944
14                 0         3664         22     2             26                970
15                 0         2209         23     2             36               1197
16                 0         1075         18     2             81               2034
17                 0         1273         18     2             16               1233
18                 0         1002         18     2            275               1790
19                 0         1002         18     2            275               1790
20                 0         1002         18     2            275               1790
21                 0         1002         18     2            275               1790
22                 0          353         11     2             44                420
23                 0           69         11     1            105               1100
24                 0         1573         11     2             45               1958
25                 0            2         34     2            293                166
26                 0           69         18     1             74               1900
27                 0          544         18     2             15               1985
28                 0          544         18     2             15               1985
29                 0           69         18     1             17               2167
30                 0         2296         11     2            273                237
```

As you can see from above this data is category data. I want to cluster this data by using K MEANS to find similar behaviour within households. There are 2500 unique households and each row represents each transaction made for each unique product. there are in total 93000 unique products.

I understand I need to pre process this data one step more before I can use the K means clustering.

Something I thought of was

```
library(dplyr)
randomtest <- mydata %>% group_by(household_key) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum),QUANTITY, SALES_VALUE, RETAIL_DISC, COUPON_DISC)
```

the code above gives me the sum of quantity, sales_value, retail_disc and coupon_disc for each household. I used this data frame to do my clustering by removing the household key.

due to lack of reputations I can not plot the results I got.

However looking at this result I don't think there is anything meaningful I can find which describes the behaviour for the households.

I am in need of some serious help where someone can suggest me some more ideas of pre processing this data so when I do the clustering it outputs me something meaningful.

I have tried many other things aswell but each time I got results which didn't make sense. I am sure I am close to the answer just need some help with silly mistakes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: +1 for use of summarise_each, which I had not seen before.

Comment: For you actual question; you do have to have a row per household if you want to cluster, but you might not want to ignore different product types.  Try adding cols for these with just the amount purchased for that product.  If there are too many products, can look for those that occur often, or those would use differs a lot.

Comment: @kasterma thank you for replying, I have in total 93,000 products. Do you mean find the mode for each household against product they bought and based on that sum the total cost and do clustering? If I do this what am I expecting to see?

Comment: My first conjecture to test would be that there are 10 (random conveniently small number) products that have something to say about households.  I would first look at the 10 most purchased products and see if they can be used to satisfy this conjecture.  So find the 10 most purchased products, and then for those products find how often each household purchased them.  On those counts do clustering.